# My delete function deletes the wrong record of struct

Tags: c, struct, binaryfiles

I have this function which is supposed to delete the recipe requested by the user. I've always deleted records in this way, but I don't know why this time it doesn't work in the right way. Sometimes it states that there's no match but it deletes the recipe or it deletes all the recipes inside the file and I don't get it why since I basically created a temp file in which writing all the records except for the one the user wants to delete and I used a function that worked for another record so I really don't get it. Is that because the length of ingredients and procedure is not the same for all the recipes?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int stringCmpi (char *s1,char *s2);

struct _recipe
{
    char name[40];
    int count_i;
    char ingredients[20][40];
    char diff[12];
    int timr;
    int calories;
    int count_p;
    char procedure[30][500];
} recipe;

int main()
{
    FILE* fbr;
    FILE* temp;
    char ricetta_name[] = "ricette.bin";
    char temp_name[] = "temp.bin";
    fbr = fopen("ricette.bin", "rb");
    temp = fopen("temp.bin", "wb");
    int found = 0;
    char name_t[40];
    int i;
    char space = '\n';

    if(fbr == NULL)
    {
       printf("Couldn't open the file.\n");
       exit(1);
    }
    if(fbr == NULL)
    {
       printf("Couldn't open the file.\n");
       exit(1);
    }


    printf("Write the name of the recipe you want to delete:\n");
    fgets(name_t,sizeof(name_t),stdin);
    space = getchar();
    while(fread(&recipe,sizeof(recipe),1,fbr) && found == 0)
    {   
        if(stringCmpi(name_t,recipe.name) == 0)
        {
            found = 1;
            printf("Match found. Recipe deleted.\n");
        }

        else
        {

            fwrite(&recipe,sizeof(recipe),1,temp);

        }
            if(!found)
    {
        printf("No match.\n");
    }
    }



    fclose(fbr);
    fclose(temp);
    remove(ricetta_name);
    rename(temp_name,ricetta_name);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

int stringCmpi (char *s1,char *s2)
{
    int i=0;
    for(i=0; s1[i]!='\0'; i++)
    {
        if( toupper(s1[i])!=toupper(s2[i]) )
            return 1;           
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
while(fread(&recipe,sizeof(recipe),1,fbr) && found == 0)
```

Once you find a recipe, you exit the loop, so the remaining elements are not copied to the new file. I recommend you delete the `&& found == 0` clause.

Furthermore:

```
if(!found)
{
    printf("No match.\n");
}
```

This is actually inside the `while` loop, so it will report `No match` multiple times. Please move it outside the loop.

Comment: I tried as you said to me, but the problem is still there and I don't really get it why. It says no match for the first recipe in the record and if I try to delete the last one, it deletes the others too

Comment: Hmm, I'm not really sure what might be going on, but you could further test the return values of `fwrite()` and `fclose()` etc to see if there is an error you are not detecting.

Answer (score 1):

1. Proper indentation would help you see the actual structure of the program. This is how the posted program looks with consistent indentation:

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <string.h>

   int stringCmpi (char *s1,char *s2);

   struct _recipe
   {
       char name[40];
       int count_i;
       char ingredients[20][40];
       char diff[12];
       int timr;
       int calories;
       int count_p;
       char procedure[30][500];
   } recipe;

   int main()
   {
       FILE* fbr;
       FILE* temp;
       char ricetta_name[] = "ricette.bin";
       char temp_name[] = "temp.bin";
       fbr = fopen("ricette.bin", "rb");
       temp = fopen("temp.bin", "wb");
       int found = 0;
       char name_t[40];
       int i;
       char space = '\n';

       if(fbr == NULL)
       {
           printf("Couldn't open the file.\n");
           exit(1);
       }
       if(fbr == NULL)
       {
           printf("Couldn't open the file.\n");
           exit(1);
       }

       printf("Write the name of the recipe you want to delete:\n");
       fgets(name_t,sizeof(name_t),stdin);
       space = getchar();
       while(fread(&recipe,sizeof(recipe),1,fbr) && found == 0)
       {
           if(stringCmpi(name_t,recipe.name) == 0)
           {
               found = 1;
               printf("Match found. Recipe deleted.\n");
           }

           else
           {
               fwrite(&recipe,sizeof(recipe),1,temp);
           }
           if(!found)
           {
               printf("No match.\n");
           }
       }

       fclose(fbr);
       fclose(temp);
       remove(ricetta_name);
       rename(temp_name,ricetta_name);
       system("PAUSE");
       return 0;
   }

   int stringCmpi (char *s1,char *s2)
   {
       int i=0;
       for(i=0; s1[i]!='\0'; i++)
       {
           if( toupper(s1[i])!=toupper(s2[i]) )
               return 1;
       }
       return 0;
   }
   ```
2. The program is checking that `fbr` is not NULL twice. Probably the second check should be for `temp`.
3. The programs stops reading and copying when the recipe to be deleted is found; this means that the following records are not copied over.
4. The program complains that the recipe was not found for each recipe until the desired one is found.

Suggestions:

- Modify the `while` loop condition eliminating the `&& ! found`, so that all records are copied except those matching the given name.
- Move the check for `if (! found)` outside the loop.

Bonus:

- The function `stringCmpi()` stops comparing at the end of string `s1`; which means that "abc" and "abcdef" will compare equal. You probably want to change `return 0` to `return s1 [i] != s2 [i]`.

Comment: I tried as you suggested but the problem is still there and I don't get it why

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct _recipe
{
    char name[40];
    int count_i;
    char ingredients[20][40];
    char diff[12];
    int timr;
    int calories;
    int count_p;
    char procedure[30][500];
} recipe;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE* fbr;
    FILE* temp;
    char *ricetta_name = "recipe.bin";
    char *temp_name = "temp.bin";
    int found = 0;
    char name_t[40];

    // Use command line arguments if possible
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        ricetta_name = argv[1];
    }

    if((fbr = fopen(ricetta_name, "rb")) == NULL)
    {
       printf("Couldn't open the file %s.\n", ricetta_name);
       exit(1);
    }
    if((temp = fopen(temp_name, "wb")) == NULL)
    {
       printf("Couldn't open the file %s.\n", temp_name);
       exit(1);
    }

    printf("Write the name of the recipe you want to delete:\n");
    fgets(name_t, sizeof(name_t), stdin);

    // Remove '\n'
    if (name_t[strlen(name_t) - 1] == '\n')
        name_t[strlen(name_t) - 1] = 0;

    while(fread(&recipe,sizeof(recipe), 1, fbr))
    {  
        // Use standard strcasecmp()
        if(strcasecmp(name_t, recipe.name) == 0)
        {
            found = 1;
            printf("Match found. Recipe deleted.\n");
        }
        else
        {
            fwrite(&recipe, sizeof(recipe), 1, temp);
        }
    }

    if (!found)
    {
        printf("No match.\n");
    }

    fclose(fbr);
    fclose(temp);
    remove(ricetta_name);
    rename(temp_name,ricetta_name);
    return 0;
}
```

Please format your code: add space(' ') after comma(','). And use standard function if possible.

Comment: I didn't use the standard function because my recipes have spaces and that function won't work with that kind of strings, that's why I was forced to write another one

Comment: `str*cmp()` just compares string no matter what they are. Why do you think it doesn't work with spaces? `strcasecmp("a b  c   d", "a b  c   d")` just returns 0.

Comment: Because when I tried it, it always states there's no match. But the problem is even with strcasecmp, it deletes the recipe from the first to the last even if I write the name of the last one

Comment: Did you meant that `strcasecmp()` always returns 0? Can you try my code? It works well for me. I wrote 10 recipes structure whose names are `name0`, ..., `name9` in a file, and it correctly removed what I specified.

Comment: I tried your code, but for the system the string comparison is always false, so it doesn't delete anything and I don't know why

Comment: Just print your strings to see what happened, `printf("cmp(<%s>, <%s>)=%d\n", s1, s2, *cmp(s1, s2))`. I guess the reason is space(` `) or newline ('\n') in string.

Comment: Oh don't worry I solvedi it, I just had to leave the newline on the string since I saved it on my file with the newline too, thank you